# custom checkboxes/radio buttons

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

Thanks for advance for assisting me with my question.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience on making custom checkboxes/radio buttons.  I have created one of each on the stage.  The goal is to create each in a movie clip so that I can use them in various programs.  As I am using these flash programs in an interface down the road, I have found myself to have trouble with the prebuild flash components.  I would like to build my own.  If you have any advice or suggestion to where I may find help please let me know.  I would also like them to be able to only have one clicked at a time.

quick note: I have the buttons both changing their stages in movieclips.  Frame 1 is the upstate and frame 2 is the down state.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have built various GUI components from scratch in Flash myself, including check boxes, radio groups, on screen keyboard, UIScrollView and date picker related things for touch screens, etc...

**My general piece of advice, avoid building components from scratch whenever possible as there are many built in methods and other general functionality that we all take for granted.**

I am not a fan of the pre-built Flash components myself, especially for touch screens. Before considering building from scratch I recommend you look into skinning the components you want. There is plently of help for this online, including:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/skinning_flash_cs3.html?PID=4176632

I did hear somewhere that Flex will be getting (or already has) some mobile GUI compenets designed for mobile devices, which presumably can be using on desktop as well. Don't recall where exactly though.

Another option is this guy's recreation of GUI stuff, available on GitHub:
http://custardbelly.com/blog/2010/08/24/introducing-as3flobile-components/

Click on the demo image and under "miscelany' you will find a good radio group example. (This guy is named Todd too, so you should trust him :)

Only after ALL the above options are deemed no bueno, then proceed with building from scratch. The check box / radio group class I made (which I cannot release) was by far the most basic of the components I have created, so it might not be as bad as recreating any of the other components. What I did was make a base radio class, then added radio buttons dynamically to a radio group. Adding the appropriated logic where needed.

I hope that helps a little and good luck!

Answer (score -1):

**Create a Custom Radio Button from Scratch Using Flash**

You can use a 3frames from your shape as a radio button.

e.g.:

1-for enable and did not choose [image]

1.2-for for enable and choose [image]

3-for disable and can not choose [image]

You can these image import to three frames and use `gotoAndStop()`

this is a example class:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public function Main():void
        {
            active.stop();
            inactive.gotoAndStop(3);
            enabledBox.gotoAndStop(2);
            active.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, changeState);
        }

        private function changeState(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (e.target.currentFrame == 1)
            {
                e.target.gotoAndStop(2);
                statusField.text = "[Enabled]";
            }
            else
            {
                e.target.gotoAndStop(1);
                statusField.text = "[Disabled]";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For full details you can use it:

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-radio-button-from-scratch-using-flash--active-4294

Comment: The answer is completed.